# how to pass session id in the email notification - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Am trying to login users through a link in email sent after registration.

In my registration method I have the following code

```
$user_id = $user->id;
Session::put('userId', $user_id);
Auth::login($user_id);
Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]);
$email = $request->email;
if($email != ''){
  $send = app()->make(\Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);
  $send->send('emails.welcome', compact('r_message', 'username', 'passwordcode', 'user_id'), function($r_message) use ($email, $username) {
  $r_message
  ->from('adun@demovalley.com')
  ->to($email, $username)
  ->subject('Welcome to Admiralty University!');
  });
}
```

while I passed the session like this on the like

```
<a href="{{ route('jamb/'. $user_id) }}">Click here</a>
```

My route

```
Route::get('jamb/{user}', ['as' => 'jamb', 'uses' => 'CandidateController@jamb']);
```

but I get this error message.

```
 ErrorException (E_ERROR)
 Route [jamb/66] not defined.
```

How can I make this to work?

Comment: The error simply says route is not defined. Show us the route file.

Comment: the `route` helper is for route names, not paths/URIs ... it takes a route name and parameters

Comment: simply write `{{jamb/$user_id}}` it will work fine

Comment: @FullSTack01 have added my route

Comment: @lagbox it is a named route

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix your routing to how you declared it to your configuration.
This:

```
 <a href="{{ route('jamb/'. $user_id) }}">
```

must be like

```
 <a href="{{ route('jamb', $user_id) }}">
```

wherein in your web.php you declared something like:

```
Route::get('jamb/{user}', 'yourController@yourMethod')->name('jamb');
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I made the changes you mentioned but am getting  ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Missing required parameters for [Route: jamb] [URI: jamb/{user}]

Comment: what is your href?  it should be  <a href="{{ route('jamb', $user_id) }}">